# Reference request: Calculus 3 from Differential Geometry perspective

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, reference-request

I am looking for a book (or chapter, section, etc.) that explains multivariable integration, line integrals and other "Calculus 3" (so-called in the USA) integration topics from a differential geometry point of view. I need to re-learn this material and want to do so in a way that connects to my background in DG.

Also, I should note: I need to re-learn multivariable integration within a short period of time, so I am not interested in a lengthy text which would require me to first learn additional prerequisites (such as, e.g., topics from physical science). Also, my background in analysis is comparatively weak, so I would not prefer an "analysis-flavored" text.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What is your background in DG?

Comment: Mostly I studied basic smooth manifold theory (tangent space, vector fields, etc.), selected topics from Riemannian geometry (geodesics, Levi-Civita connection, curvature tensor, etc.), as well as some topics from "classical" DG (sectional curvature, curves and surfaces in euclidean space, etc.). I haven't got far into more advanced topics like differential forms and cohomology.

Comment: Okay. It seems it is easier to learn differential form, exterior derivative and Stokes theorem, and then reduces to the lower dimensional case. Looks like you've had basic understanding in tensors, so it should be okay.

Comment: Given that you already have all these DG topics as background knowledge, I feel like you can easily speed through Spivak's calculus on manifolds. Chapter 3 is about integration in $\Bbb{R}^n$ (basic definitions, 'Fubini' and Change of Variables), chapter 4 introduces tensors and forms, and chapter 5 culminates in Stokes' theorem (Spivak only treats submanifolds of $\Bbb{R}^n$, but given your DG knowledge you should easily be able to transcribe the proof to work for abstract manifolds as well). If you want a slightly slower-paced book, then Hubbard and Hubbard's book is also pretty nice

Comment: Actually, what I'd recommend is that you quickly learn the definitions from Spivak (C3,4,5, but I'm sure you can skim through several portions), and then try to solve all the problems in Chapter 6 of Hubbard and Hubbard, because they are more Calc 2/3 type of problems but involving differential forms, as opposed to Spivak where sometimes you can get stuck on problems forever (which can be a good thing, but given your time constraints, probably not ideal), and these problems will also help you practice your multivariable integration.

Comment: @peek-a-boo thank you for this detailed suggestion. I've heard good things about Calculus on Manifolds. And you're exactly right that it would not be ideal to get stuck on exercises for a while, so I like the idea of going to Hubbard and Hubbard for the exercises! This sounds like a perfect plan - Thanks so much!